# Use static function from service in component template

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, expression

I have created a simple service (MyService) which has a static public function 
called hello which returns the string "hello"

In another component I import the MyService and want to place the hello output in an expression in a template like so:

```
{{ myService.hello() }}
```

I was able to make this work with a non-static method (using the instance injected in the component constructor):

```
{{ myInstance.hello() }}
```

but I can't seem to do the equivalent using the static method.  The browser complains that hello is not a function.  Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods can't be used in the template directly.
The scope of the template is the component instance and in bindings only identifiers from this scope can be referenced.

```
export class MyComponent {
  hello = MyService.hello
}
```

allows

```
{{hello()}}
```